# theme ALL form elements in a tpl through hook_preprocess_HOOK

Tags: forms, theming

Trying to theme a form into all the pieces available, passed my $form and $vars through hook_preprocess_HOOK but in my tpl i would like the exact render() representation of the fields and variables and the form itself like:

```
print $form_tag.
      $form_input1.
      $form_input2.
      $theme_var1.
      $form_closure; <!-- build_id,token_id -->
 ?>
```

Where there are declared in the preprosess_HOOK as

```
$form = $variables['form'];
$variables['form_tag'] = render($form); 
$variables['form_input1'] = render($form['input1']);
$variables['closure'] = drupal_render_children($form);
...
```

Is it possible to have all this variables of produced HTML in my tpl?
 like form start tag and closure and render correctly all the inner fields?
Thank you

Comment: is this a form you have created or a form in core or drupal modules?

Comment: this is a form in a custom module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is simple , i returned the content using a theme function e.g.

```
return theme('mytheme',$form)
```

Entering

```
$form['#theme']
```

in the form array and

```
'render element' => form
```

in my hook_theme solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to do. But from the question I feel that you just want to re arrange the form in an order of your choice.

The best place to do that is with in a hook_form_alter function. Rather than the preprocess_HOOK.

Every form element has a property called **#weight** This could be used to arrange the forms in order the one with higher weight would go down.

Comment: Thanks mohammad but the form is arranged. 
I need to produce a template that has every element of the form available for themer for example and a theme_hook on his template of the theme to have the variables available also
like:

    $form_tag = <form id="" ...>
    $fieldset = <fieldset> .. </fieldset>
    $closure = <input type="hidden" build_id etc ..
is this possible?

Comment: what would be the use case?

Comment: 100% front end handling of things in the template